# XLA file not saving in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, xla, vba

I'm using Excel 2010 and I have a `.xla` file with VBA macros, I edit the macros with the VBA editor, then save it. Later when I reopen the `.xla` file my changes are lost. On the internet I found other people with the same problem, e.g. [MS-Excel VBA file (XLA) saving problem](https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/ms-excel-vba-file-xla-saving-problem.2951769/), but not solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try to save it in the VBA-Editor. This ist what I have to do with xlam-files.

Comment: Funny it worked now. I closed all the `.xls` files and just kept the VBA editor open, then saved it.